# Functions that work the same in encode URL in Javascript and PHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, urlencode

I've been looking for the functions [used to encode and decode URL] that can be exchangable between PHP and Javascript [I can encode the URL in javascript and decode it in PHP and vice versa], there are many solutions come up, like escape() and unescape(); encodeURI() and decodeURI() for javascript, or urlencode() and urldecode() for PHP, but there is no pair which can works together perfectly. Because I want to send post data using Ajax jQuery for a PHP page to use, and data can be mixed with special character, that's why I need a function that works the same in PHP and Javascript:

Example:

```
$.ajax{url: "test.php", data: "http://www.thisURLContainSpecialCharac.ter"}
```

See the code above? It contains special characters in data, that may cause problem.

I appreciate any advice :). Thanks.
[x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use Javascript's `escape` function since it does not URL encode.  See http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/ for examples where it fails.

Javascript's [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) will encode assuming UTF-8, so if you use that and make sure that your request has a content-type of UTF-8, you should be able to decode in PHP using

[utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)`(`[urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)`($yourString))`.

Comment: Can you give me an example? In js and php? [x]

Comment: How are you sending data?  Are you passing it in a GET URL, or in a POST message body?

Comment: @Mike Samuel: I use POST, but I it works both ways. Why does it matter? [x]

Comment: @xx3004, I can't give you an example without knowing what you're doing.  There seems to be a typo in "but I it works both ways".  Could you please clarify.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: I use POST, but I've made a function that auto detect POST or GET. So it doesn't matter. The problem is, I am afraid that if user POST [or either type in url GET] a string with special characters: Example: `check.php&link=C:\Programs\A_Buch~Of♥Special#Characters` then there would be a problem. I wish that Javascript can encode special characters, and PHP decode them to get the original message. Do you understand me? [x]

Comment: @xx3004, JavaScript can encode special characters passed to a JavaScript function.  JavaScript does not sit between the browser URL bar and your system though.  The browser should make sure that only well-formed URLs reach your server, but you should not rely on it doing so.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: So can I just make it send without worrying about errors? [x]

Comment: What is it, and what is it sending to whom?  If it is the user sitting at their browser in the URL bar, then you have no control about what they enter so don't worry.  If it is some JavaScript code that you wrote, running in the server, then worry about it by using `encodeURIComponent`.  Regardless of what is sending the message, your server code always needs to check that messages it receives are well-formed and authorized.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: Thanks, that's what I am asking for, the javascript runs and sends the code to a sever.php to process [it's like when you submit a form, but in this case, ajax it], but it receive data to send through an input, that could contain special characters. Does my php need to decode the received data since when we send we encodeURIComponent it? [x]

Comment: If the post body has the content type header set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then PHP should automatically decode it.  If the content is sent via the query part of the URL as part of a GET or POST request, then again, PHP should automatically decode it.  The only time you need to decode is when you are using a funky content-type with a POST body.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: Gotcha, problem solved. Thank you very much. [x]